# Know clicked view using ButterKnife

Tags: android, events, click, butterknife

I have this code :

```
@OnClick( {R.id.iv_first,R.id.iv_second} )
public void launchCards() {
    Log.i(TAG,"clicked");
}
```

Is there a way to know inside the `launchCards()` method which of the two `ImageView` has been clicked ?

Comment: witch kind of view are these R.id.iv_first and R.id.iv_second?

Comment: These are just two ImageView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@OnClick({R.id.iv_first,R.id.iv_second}) 
public void launchCards(View view) {

        // Check which ImageView was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
          case R.id.iv_first:
              // 1 clicked
            break;
          case R.id.iv_second:
              // 2 clicked
            break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your gentle answer even if the answer was in front of me in the official doc but I missed it....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reading the documentation at http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ wouldn't hurt - just change your method signature to `launchCards(View v)` and then use `v.getId()` inside your function.

Hope this helps you, comment if you have any questions

Comment: Maybe be nice wouldn't hurt :) I checked the doc but missed this one, yes this happen to me sometimes when I work for whole day switching from my project and random online docs, i miss evidences. Anyway it was helpful, thank you.

Comment: Calm down, I didn't mean it the bad way. Anyway, I am happy to know it helped you